# check option select ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to check the length of an array of values inside ng-repeat, depends of that, I have to add or an `<option>` or `<optgroup>`.

The ng-repeat look like this:

```
<select name="countries">
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries">{{ country.country_name }}</option>
</select>
```

And the 'countries' is an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
       country_name: "Argentina"
       language: Array[2]
       locale_code: "AR"
    },
    {
       country_name: "Austria"
       language: Array[1]
       locale_code: "AR"
    },
    ....
    ....
]
```

The code should look like this, but in angular way:

```
<select name="countries">
    for (var i; i < countries.length; i++) {
      if (countries[i].languages.length > 1) {
      <optgroup value="{{ i }}" label="{{ country.country_name }}">
         for (var j; j < countries[i].languages.length; i++) { 
         <option value="{{ countries[i].languages[j].value }}">{{ countries[i].languages[j].name }}</option>
         }
      </optgroup>
      } else {
      <option value="{{ countries[i].languages[0].value }}">{{ countries[i].languages[0].name }}</option>
      }
    }
</select>
```

Any clue how to do it with angular template?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just use  ng-if="country.languages.length==1" and ng-if="country.languages.length>1" in the same way you use it on the non angular template

Comment: That way I have to do two ng-repeat, one for option and another for optgroup... it'll all be duplicated, correct?

Comment: If it's to make grouped option, you can also take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions  groupBy in optional options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is tricky since you are only allowed `<option>` or `<optgroup>` inside `<select>`.

One way to achieve this is to have two separate `ng-repeat`s in combination with `ng-if`, but this will mess up the order of values.

The most appropriate way is to use `ng-repeat-start`/`ng-repeat-end` in combination with `ng-if`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedLanguage">
  <optgroup ng-repeat-start="country in countries" 
            ng-if="country.language.length > 1" 
            label="{{country.country_name}}">
    <option ng-repeat="lang in country.language" 
            value="{{lang}}">{{lang}}</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option ng-repeat-end 
          ng-if="country.language.length === 1" 
          value="{{country.language[0]}}">
    {{country.language[0]}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/l9qXF0ytm5qyGv8J6oiM?p=preview)**

Comment: I'm checking it in my code, thanks for you response. I will let you know